# Making a function constructor function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

How, if possible, do I create a function constructor function?..a constructor that also has prototype methods.

I know how to create an object constructor function i.e.

```
Function Thing(val) { this.prop1 = val  }
Thing.prototype.action = function()...
```

But to make create a new function with prototype prop and methods, the best I can come up with is, for example:

```
Function Func(val) { 
   var func = function(x) {return val*x};
   func.val = val;
   func.__proto__ = proto;
   return func;
}

const proto = {
   product: function(x) { return this.val*x },
};
```

For the sake of code hygiene, is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf()`

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
function Person(name) {  
  this.name = name;
}
// create a new instance
var person = new Person('codechimp');
console.log('person.constructor is ' + person.constructor);
```